# Best way to mange bundled script files and CDN jquery files in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My default ASP.NET MVC 4 project has bundles created for JQuery and JQuery UI that is referenced in the pages.
I want to change this to use an absolute link from a CDN instead of relative on my web server.

I thought it could be as simple as just changing the url's in the bundles to point to the CDN urls. I understand why this won't work because bundles essentially bundle everything up into one file.  These cases, I only have one file though.

I'm wondering.  What is the best practice here.  Basically, I want the code to exist in my layout or even individual pages that directs the view to load the script tags for these scrips.  Then I can manage which script tags are included.  The same way we do it with bundling, but I want it to work by doing the bundling and also do any other alternative script tags instead of the bundle.  This way I can swap in and out depending on how I feel I want to manage my scrips at any one time.  Let's say I want to add another js file to the bundle some day, or I want to include another script that will have it's script tag rendered on every page.  I want a central place to do this.

Thoughts?

Comment: bundling & cdn are opposites in solving the same problem. cdn should mean you don't download the same files again & again. bundles reduce the amount of files downloaded. There is therefore no need to bundle cdn files.

Comment: Thanks, but that's my point.  I want to be able to have one piece of markup in a view file that will create the pages script tags.  These script tags will consist of both bundled and non bundled scrips.  I think what I need to do is have Razor markup to render the bundled scripts, and another markup to render the non bundled scripts, and then just manage which scripts get bundled and which get rendered as individual script tags.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. Can you use a cdn with bundling? Yes, with the `useCdn = true` and the optional `cdnPath` second parameter on the bundle constructor. Can you package your bundles in groups and use Razor conditional statements to selectively load bundles? Yes, I do it all the time.